# Identification in Cloud Form

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Can I associate a submitted `FormFunction` data with a user ( by `$WolframID` or whatever)?

It can be restricted to the case where `"Permissions"` to execute are given to the list of users or to `"Authenticated"` users. E.g.:

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{"first" -> "String"}, $WolframID &]
 ,
 Permissions -> {"Authenticated" -> "Execute"}
]
```

Here `$WolframID` will evaluate to the ID of the account where the `CloudObject` is.

Comment: What about `$RequesterWolframID`?

Comment: @C.E. That I have missed. Consider voting to close or posting an answer, up to you :)

Comment: @Kuba -- For my part I think you've asked a good and useful question.  We can't expect everyone to keep the entire contents of the documentation and their applications in their heads.

Comment: @Kuba I didn't know what to do, luckily someone else posted so now it's up to others to decide what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like:

```
CloudDeploy[
   FormFunction[formspec,
      If[$RequesterWolframID === None,
         HTTPResponse[ExportForm["Please login ...", "JSON"], <|"StatusCode"->403|> ],
         processformfunctioninput]& ],
    FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory,"RequireAuthentication"}] ]
```